# VisualStudio Multi Item Reports with multiple repeated subreports

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, report

I am working on a C# project in VisualStudio 2010 and am trying to generate a more than simple report with multiple datasources (lists of business objects).  I'm not using crystal reports.

I have an inventory of items with data about sales for each item.  What I would like to do is to have each item number displayed in a header of sorts for that specific item.  Underneath each item I will have two separate subreports made of tables of information related to that specific item.

I was able to do this for a single item, but I do not know how to get the format to repeat for each of my top level business objects (the items).

I have not been able to find any tutorials or other information as to how to accomplish this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.